# R Plotly: Smooth Transition in 3D Animations

Tags: r, animation, plotly

I want to achieve smooth transitions between the frames of 3D scatter plots in plotly.
For 2D data, this apparently works automatically when no further parameters are defined:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, frame = ~cyl)
```

Note that the points "move" inbetween the frames to their target location.

However, for 3D data, the animation will be abrupt (and adjusts the range of my axes):

```
plot_ly(mtcars, mode = "markers", type = "scatter3d", x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, z= ~disp, frame = ~cyl)
```

Is there any way to have my points glide from one location to another in 3D plots?

Answer (score 1):

You need using the duration and easing can significantly affect the smoothness of the transition.

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  data = mtcars, 
  x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, z = ~disp, 
  type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers",
  frame = ~cyl
)

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  scene = list(
    xaxis = list(range = c(min(mtcars$wt), max(mtcars$wt))),
    yaxis = list(range = c(min(mtcars$mpg), max(mtcars$mpg))),
    zaxis = list(range = c(min(mtcars$disp), max(mtcars$disp)))
  ),
  transition = list(duration = 1000, easing = "cubic-in-out")
)

fig
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I've already toyed with the 'duration' and 'easing' but couldn't find any satisfying solution. Due to the scene settings the axes are now fixed. However, the transition still isn't "gliding" in the example you provided. The points appear to "jump" from frame to frame. (I'm working on Win10, RStudio)